# if monic polynomial divides product, then it must divide at least one of them

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $F$ is a field and let $c \in F$. say $f(x),g(x) \in F[x]$. IF $x-c$ divides $f(x)g(x)$, then $x-c$ divides at least one of $f(x)$ or $g(x)$.

#### try

We know that can find unique $q_i(x) \in  F[x]$ and unique $r_i \in F$ such that $f(x) = (x-c)p_1 + r_1$ and $g(x) = (x-c)p_2 + r_2$. So,

$$ fg(x) = (x-c)( (x-c)p_1p_2  + p_1r_2 + p_2r_1) + r_1r_2 $$

since $x-c$ divides $fg$, then it must divide $r_1r_2$

but, then here I am stuck. I dont know how to procced from here. Any help? is my approach so good so far?

Comment: This much is true for any *prime* element in an integral domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If $x-c$ divides $f(x)g(x)$ then $c$ is a root of $f(x)g(x)$.

So $f(c)g(c)=0$ and consequently $f(c)=0$ or $g(c)=0$.